# Cannot scrape Booking's results on query

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I am new to Web scraping using PHP but not to PHP itself. The issue I have is not regex related but seems to be related to the booking.com website directly. I would like to scrape hotel's prices in a particular city. To do so, I copied the URL from my browser in the booking page and I pasted it in my code.

[This](http://www.booking.com/searchresults.en.html?dcid=1;checkin_monthday=25;checkin_year_month=2014-7;checkout_monthday=26;checkout_year_month=2014-7;city=-1461464;class_interval=1;csflt=%7B%7D;interval_of_time=undef;no_rooms=1;or_radius=0;property_room_info=1;review_score_group=empty;score_min=0;src=city;ssb=empty;;nflt=ht_id%3D204%3Bclass%3D3%3B;unchecked_filter=class) is the page.

Here is my code:

```
    <?php

function getHTML($url,$timeout)
{
       $ch = curl_init($url); // initialize curl with given url
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]); // set  useragent
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // write the response to a variable
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // follow redirects if any
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout); // max. seconds to execute
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1); // stop when it encounters an error
       return @curl_exec($ch);
}

$html=getHTML("http://www.booking.com/searchresults.en.html?dcid=1;checkin_monthday=25;checkin_year_month=2014-7;checkout_monthday=26;checkout_year_month=2014-7;city=-1461464;class_interval=1;csflt=%7B%7D;interval_of_time=undef;no_rooms=1;or_radius=0;property_room_info=1;review_score_group=empty;score_min=0;src=city;ssb=empty;;nflt=ht_id%3D204%3Bclass%3D3%3B;unchecked_filter=class",10);

echo $html;

?>
```

I do get a booking page printed out but it's like it didn't take into account the parameters in the URL, because on the page I get it asks for a booking date & city...

I tried pasting this URL in several browsers and incognito windows (to see if the URL was linked to Cookies or something), and it worked fine. Maybe I'm missing an argument in the cURL request...

Comment: Thank you. I think I will try using this instead: CasperJS ( http://casperjs.org/ )

Answer (score 5):

I finally solved this issue. I just had to send the browser's headers to the website.
Here is the code:

```
function getHTML($url,$timeout)
{
        $header = array();
        $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
        $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
        $header[] =  "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
        $header[] =  "Connection: keep-alive";
        $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
        $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
        $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
        $header[] = "Pragma: "; // browsers keep this blank.

       $ch = curl_init($url); // initialize curl with given url
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]); // set  useragent
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // write the response to a variable
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // follow redirects if any
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout); // max. seconds to execute
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1); // stop when it encounters an error
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true );
       return @curl_exec($ch);
}

$url = "booking url...";
echo getHTML($url,10);
```

The solution was so simple...

Comment: Indeed, you only need `User-Agent` and `Accept-Charset`headers